# Read 3 1xN arrays into a 3xN matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 3 arrays in matlab that are 1xN, X Y Z respectively. I need to read these arrays into a 3xN matrix respectively so I get

```
x1 y1 z1 
x2 y2 z2
.. .. ..
xn yn zn
```

I have currently got the data in a Nx 3 matrix, the wrong way round. The code I have is

```
X = [];
Y = [];
Z = [];
for ctr = 1:length(A)
    X = [X A(ctr,1)];
    Y = [Y A(ctr,2)];
    Z = [Z A(ctr,3)];
end

M = [X;Y;Z];
```

Where A is the input data from a 624*600 double cell and M is my desired matrix.

Thanks

Comment: If `A` has all of your data already, what's the point in extracting out each row? Why don't you just simply transpose `A`?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that you can transpose with `Mt = transpose(M);` which has the overall intended result but feels like 3 rights to make a left.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want that:

```
X = [];
Y = [];
Z = [];
for ctr = 1:length(A)
  X(end+1, 1) = A(ctr,1);
  Y(end+1, 1) = A(ctr,2);
  Z(end+1, 1) = A(ctr,3);
end

M = [X Y Z];
```

Faster with 1 line code:

```
M = [A(:, 1) A(:, 2) A(:, 3)];
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'most efficient way'? In execution time, or ?

Comment: Amount of code, execution time and readability. The data is already in 3 separate vectors. It's more efficient to stack the vectors column wise and transpose the result.

Comment: Transpose `M` and you're solid. You can simply just do `M = A.';` but I don't know of the data is already in a matrix or if they're separate vectors now that I read the question. The OP switches back and forth.

Comment: need the questioner's confirmation. I thought he meant A is the input data matrix which has size of 624*600 ...

Comment: Agree with you there. Either way +1 from me :)